# extract decimal numbers from string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I would like to extract decimal numbers (at least with 2 decimal places)
I tried this:

```
$myString = 'Rechnung WEEE-Reg.-Nr. DE 89633988, Batterie-Reg.-Nr. 21003868 LU-BIO-04 Amazon EU S.à r.l. - 38 avenue John F. Kennedy, L-1855 Luxembourg Sitz der Gesellschaft: L-1855 Luxemburg eingetragen im Luxemburgischen Handelsregister unter R.C.S. B 101818 • Stammkapital: 37.500 EUR Amazon EU S.à r.l., Niederlassung Deutschland – Marcel-Breuer-Str. 12, D-80807 München, Deutschland Sitz der Zweigniederlassung: München eingetragen im Handelsregister des Amtsgerichts München unter HRB 218574 USt-ID : DE 814584193 Seite 1 von 1 USt. y Zwischensumme (ohne USt.) USt. 19y 47,05 € 8,94 € USt. Gesamt 47,05 € 8,94 € Gesamtpreis 55,99 € Rechnungsdetails Bestelldatum 04 Oktober 2021 Bestellnummer XXXXXX Zahlungsreferenznummer XXXXX Verkauft von Amazon EU S.à r.l., Niederlassung Deutschland USt-IDNr. DE814584193 Rechnungsdatum /Lieferdatum 05 Oktober 2021 Rechnungsnummer XXXXX Zahlbetrag 55,99 € XXXXXX Um unseren Kundenservice zu kontaktieren, besuchen Sie www.amazon.de/contact-us Rechnungsadresse XXXXXXXX Lieferadresse XXXXXXX Verkauft von Amazon EU S.à r.l., Niederlassung Deutschland Marcel-Breuer-Str. 12 80807 München Deutschland USt-IDNr. DE814584193 Bestellinformationen Beschreibung Menge Stückpreis (ohne USt.) USt. y Stückpreis (inkl. USt.) Zwischensumme (inkl. USt.) AVM FRITZ!WLAN Mesh Repeater 1200 (Zwei Funkeinheiten: 5 GHz (bis zu 866 MBit/s), 2,4 GHz (bis zu 400 MBit/s), 1x Gigabit-LAN, deutschsprachige Version) ASIN: B07V3TKDV5 1 47,05 € 19yb 55,99 € 55,99 € Versandkosten 0,00 € 0,00 € 0,00 €'

preg_match_all('!\d+\.*\d*!', $myString, $matches);
```

My Output:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 89633988
            [1] => 21003868
            [2] => 04
            [3] => 38
            [4] => 1855
            [5] => 1855
            [6] => 101818
            [7] => 37.500
            [8] => 12
            [9] => 80807
            [10] => 218574
            [11] => 814584193
            [12] => 1
            [13] => 1
)
```

The only correct value is 37.500 which I would like to have in my array.
Where is my mistake ? :/

** UPDATE **

```
preg_match_all('!\d+\.\d*!', $myString, $matches);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 89633988,
            [1] => 12,
            [2] => 47,05
            [3] => 8,94
            [4] => 47,05
            [5] => 8,94
            [6] => 55,99
            [7] => 55,99
            [8] => 2,4
            [9] => 47,05
            [10] => 55,99
            [11] => 55,99
            [12] => 0,00
            [13] => 0,00
            [14] => 0,00
        )

)
```

Better but not perfect. 0,1 and 8 are wrong.

Comment: Would you share us your input string?

Comment: The `*` means to match _zero or more_ times.  If you want to _require_ a decimal point, then don't use `\.*`.

Comment: Also looks like you have European format decimals, so need `(\.|,)`

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: [`(\d{0,}[.,]{1}\d{2,})`](https://regex101.com/r/aoHBEv/1)

Comment: Using `\d+\.\d*` can not match `89633988,` `12,` or `2,4` To match 1+ digits with a dot and at least 2 decimals: `\b\d+\.\d{2,}\b`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Good point but OP doesn't want those numbers, 2 decimal places is requirement and `,` separator apparently is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

I think:

```
\d*[.,]\d{2,}
```

achieves what you want, optional leading numbers, `.` or `,`, then 2 or more integers.

https://3v4l.org/MUIOv

**Update:**

If UK/Europe separators (`,`) are not allowed:

```
\d*[.]\d{2,}
```

should work. (optional leading numbers, `.`, then 2 or more integers.)

https://3v4l.org/cmoUt

This only provides `37.500` as a result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match at least 2 decimal places for positive and negative decimals try the following

`/[+-]?([0-9]+[\.,][0-9]{2,}|[\.,][0-9]{2,})/`

`[+-]?` matches a leading `+` or a leading `-` char or none of them before the decimal

`([0-9]+[\.,][0-9]{2,}|[\.,][0-9]{2,})`
group of matching decimals like `1.500` or without a number before the dot like `.0001` with 2 or more decimal places regarding `.` and `,`.

Comment: What's the `+-` requirement? There isn't a `g` modifier in PHP.

Comment: Well decimals can be negative, right? As we don 't know, if the questioneer is looking for positive decimals only this is a solition with respect to negative decimals too. The `g` modifier is a good hint. Removed it.

Comment: Possibly, the `+` won't be present for positive integers though.

Comment: That 's why the following `?` quantifier is for. It matches the previous tokens one or zero times.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this Regex Pattern: `\d*(,|\.)\d{2,3}`

**Output will be**

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 37.500
            [1] => 47,05
            [2] => 8,94
            [3] => 47,05
            [4] => 8,94
            [5] => 55,99
            [6] => 55,99
            [7] => 47,05
            [8] => 55,99
            [9] => 55,99
            [10] => 0,00
            [11] => 0,00
            [12] => 0,00
        )
```

And if you only need "Stammkapital" then use this reges:
`\d*(,|\.)\d{2,3} EUR`
**output will be:**

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 37.500 EUR
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 37.500
        )
```